# Typescript: assemble a union out of rest parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

See the code:

```
type FN = <U>(...rest: U[]) => U

declare const fn: FN

let union = fn('bar', 123) // Argument of type '123' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

I expected that `union` should have a union type `string | number`, but instead `U` is set to the type of the first argument (`string`).

Is it possible to push types of rest arguments to a union?

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20FN%20%3D%20%3CU%3E(...rest%3A%20U%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20U%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20fn%3A%20FN%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20union%20%3D%20fn('bar'%2C%20123))

Comment: I think your playground link contains something else ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir 10x, fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the design decisions around this, but if you have `U[]` the compiler will not infer a union for that it will rather issue an error for primitives at least (this for example results in a union `let union = fn({ a: 'bar' }, { b: 123 })`).

A simple workaround is to use tuples in rest parameters instead:

```
type FN = <U extends any[]>(...rest: U) => U[number]

declare const fn: FN

let union = fn('bar', 123) // string | number
```